# $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{2}]$ is not a complete space

Tags: complete-spaces

I am trying to prove that $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{2}]=\{a+b\sqrt{2}:a,b\in\mathbb{Q}\}$ is not a complete space (with the standard metric). For that purpose, I am looking for a Cauchy sequence in $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{2}]$ which is not convergent in $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{2}]$. Can somebody help me? Thanks!

Comment: can you think of a sequence that converges to an element of $\mathbb R\setminus\mathbb Q[\sqrt2]$?

Comment: For example, try $$3, 3.1, 3.14,3.141,3.1415, \dots$$

Comment: I think the sequence $x_{n+1}=\frac{2x_n}{3}+\frac1{x_n}$ with $x_n = 1$ converges to $\sqrt{3}$, right?

Comment: That's correct, @JN_2605

Comment: Now you just need to prove that $\sqrt3\notin\Bbb Q[\sqrt2]$.

Comment: What is the limit of the sequence $\left(1+\frac{\sqrt{2}}{n}\right)^n$?

Comment: @Arthur good point! Luckily this is adressed on this site :) https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2692648/631742

Answer (score 0):

Consider $1, 2, \dfrac32, \dfrac53, \dfrac85, \dfrac{13}8, ...$

Comment: To someone not familiar with the theory of field extensions, it is not entirely obvious that $\sqrt5\notin \Bbb Q[\sqrt2]$.

Comment: if $(a+b\sqrt2)^2=a^2+2b^2+2ab\sqrt2=5$ then $2ab=0$, so $a=0$ or $b=0$; from there it follows that $\sqrt5\not\in\mathbb Q[\sqrt2]$

Answer (score 0):

Note that $\mathbb{Q}$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$. Hence, there exists a sequence in $\mathbb{Q}$ which converges to $\sqrt{3}$. This sequence is also contained in $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{2}]$ (and it's Cauchy, because it converges) but clearly $\sqrt{3}$ is not.

Comment: "clearly $\sqrt{3}$ is not" I don't think it's that clear to someone who isn't familiar with the theory of field extensions.

Comment: As already pointed out in another comment, there is an elementary proof by contradiction. I don't even know what a field extension is.

Answer (score 0):

**Not particularly elementary, but useful** and also a continuation of my comment ...

---

Let's take an integer $k$ that is not a perfect square. Then $\sqrt{k}$ is [algebraic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_number) and irrational (root of the polynomial $x^2 -k$). It turns out that $e^{\sqrt{k}}$ is transcendental (i.e. is not algebraic, i.e. not a root of any polynomial with rational coefficients), the proof is easy, given [Lindemann–Weierstrass theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lindemann%E2%80%93Weierstrass_theorem)

> ... by the second formulation of the theorem, if $\alpha$ is a non-zero algebraic number, then $\{0, \alpha\}$ is a set of distinct algebraic numbers, and so the set $\{e^0, e^{\alpha}\} = \{1, e^{\alpha}\}$ is linearly independent over the algebraic numbers and in particular $e^\alpha$ cannot be algebraic and so it is transcendental.

---

Any element of $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{k}]= \{a+b\sqrt{k}:a,b∈Q\}$ is [algebraic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_number). From $x=a+b\sqrt{k} \Rightarrow \frac{(x-a)^2}{b^2}-k$ is the polynomial, with rational coefficients. For $b=0$ the polynomial is $x-a$.

---

$\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{k}]$is not complete, because

- $1+\frac{\sqrt{k}}{n}\in\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{k}]$ for $\forall n\in\mathbb{N}\setminus\{0\}$
- $\left(1+\frac{\sqrt{k}}{n}\right)^n\in\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{k}]$, easy to check using [Binomial_theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem)
- But $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\frac{\sqrt{k}}{n}\right)^n=e^{\sqrt{k}}$ transcendental, thus $e^{\sqrt{k}} \notin \mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{k}]$.